# Kafka Streams: serialize back to avro

Tags: avro, apache-kafka-streams

I'm trying to build a Stream that gets an Avro Topic, do a simple transformation and then sends it back again in Avro format to an other Topic and I'm kind of stuck on the final serialization part.

I have an AVRO schema created, I'm importing it and using it to create the Specific Avro Serde. But I don't know how to serialize the movie object back to AVRO using this serde.

This is the stream class:

```
class StreamsProcessor(val brokers: String, val schemaRegistryUrl: String) {

    private val logger = LogManager.getLogger(javaClass)

    fun process() {
        val streamsBuilder = StreamsBuilder()

        val avroSerde = GenericAvroSerde().apply {
            configure(mapOf(Pair("schema.registry.url", schemaRegistryUrl)), false)
        }

        val movieAvro = SpecificAvroSerde<Movie>().apply{
            configure(mapOf(Pair("schema.registry.url", schemaRegistryUrl)), false)
        }

        val movieAvroStream: KStream<String, GenericRecord> = streamsBuilder
                .stream(movieAvroTopic, Consumed.with(Serdes.String(), avroSerde))

        val movieStream: KStream<String, StreamMovie> = movieAvroStream.map {_, movieAvro ->
            val movie = StreamMovie(
                    movieId = movieAvro["name"].toString() + movieAvro["year"].toString(),
                    director = movieAvro["director"].toString(),
            )
             KeyValue("${movie.movieId}", movie)
        }

        // This where I'm stuck, the call is wrong because movieStream is not a <String, movieAvro> object 
        movieStream.to(movieTopic, Produced.with(Serdes.String(), movieAvro))

        val topology = streamsBuilder.build()

        val props = Properties()
        props["bootstrap.servers"] = brokers
        props["application.id"] = "movies-stream"
        val streams = KafkaStreams(topology, props)
        streams.start()
    }
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The type of your result stream is `KStream<String, StreamMovie>` and thus the used value Serde should be of type `SpecificAvroSerde<StreamMovie>`.

Why do you try to use `SpecificAvroSerde<Movie>`? If `Movie` is the desired output type, you should create `Movie` object in your `map` step instead of a `StreamMovie` object and change the value type of the result `KStream` accordingly.

Compare https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-streams-examples/blob/5.4.1-post/src/test/java/io/confluent/examples/streams/SpecificAvroIntegrationTest.java